# Scroll view can't perform delegate but table view can

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a scroll view to show image and set inside tableview cell. Scroll view can’t perform scroll view delegate but table view can perform the scroll view delegate.

So, how can I perform delegate only scroll view?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I mean I add "image view" to scroll view not image. I add image view into scroll view and want to horizontal scroll to show image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll in scroll view the scroll view delegate will be called but the table view will get scrolled. You can not access only scroll view delegates inside table view.

Answer (score 0):

If you add image to the scroll view, it will not scroll because you are actually scrolling the Cells and not the scroll view itself.
That's why, you need to add the image to a cell, not to the scroll view.

So in your table View delegate method where you are constructing your cells you should add the image view.